# digitize esri 9.2 or 9.3

Tags: arcgis-desktop

Is it a way to digitize indicating a curve (colored on a white or black or different colour background) from point to point ? I think i've been told that, but i don't KNOW to do it !
Please consider a quite low GIS knowleadge....(sorry)

Comment: I do not fully understand your question.  What type of feature are you digitizing (point. polyline, or polygon)?  What do you mean by "digitize indicating a curve"?  Are you looking to change the background color of the view while digitizing?

Comment: @artwork21  Sorry.. I mean to 'click' on a line/curve in the raster and to obtain the shp of the whole /or at least a part of    line.shp and NOT to Mark points then convert to lines ...

Comment: @mapperz Sorry.. I mean to 'click' on a line/curve in the raster and to obtain the shp of the whole /or at least a part of line.shp and NOT to Mark points then convert to lines ...

Answer (score 1):

You can do the curve between two lines

The points you mention are the 'Tangent Points'

[image]

Use the fillet tool [image] in the Advanced Editing toolbar in ArcGIS 9.3

You can fix the radius of the curve in the fillet options

More info
http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?id=656&pid=642&topicname=Creating_a_fillet_curve_between_two_lines